# When to use new table mySql

Tags: mysql, database-design, scalability, create-table, entities

When should one create a new table in a database and use new ids? Example in a database for tickets for concerts, should I create a new table for each concert then delete it afterwards?

Keeping all the tickets in one database with unique ID's for each does not sound like a scalable solution.

This is a theory question rather than a practical coding question.

Comment: I don't see why you need to create multiple tables? You just need one that stores ticket info, and for what concert it's for. If you delete it, how would you solve issues in the future if there is no history of a purchase etc? Unique id's in one table is fine, unless you're expecting to sell billions.

Comment: Possibly a better fit for [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) or [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com/)...

Comment: "Keeping all the tickets in one database with unique ID's for each does not sound like a scalable solution." As long as it's properly indexed, it's pretty scalable.

Comment: I was thinking that I'd rather have each ticket # for each event starting off numbered at zero. Should I have seperate ticket numbers and ticket IDs then and just keep them all in the one table?

Just seems like a monolithic way of doing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sample example of how you could do this in a relational pattern:

**SCHEMA:**

```
Table: USER

+---------------+-------------------+---------------+
|   UserID      |   First Name      |   Last Name   |
+---------------+-------------------+---------------+
|       1       |       John        |       Doe     |
|---------------|-------------------|---------------|
|       2       |       Jane        |       Doe     |
+---------------+-------------------+---------------+

Table: CONCERT

+---------------+-------------------+-----------+---------------+
|   ConcertID   |   Concert Name    |   Artist  |       Date    |
+---------------+-------------------+-----------+---------------+
|       1       |   Rock Concert    |   Rob     |   Jan-1-2014  |
|---------------|-------------------|-----------|---------------|
|       2       |   Rap Concert     |   Jay     |   Feb-3-2014  |
+---------------+-------------------+-----------+---------------+

Table: TICKET

+-----------+---------------+---------------+
|   UserID  |   ConcertID   |   Quantity    |
+-----------+---------------+---------------+
|     1     |       1       |       1       |
|-----------|---------------|---------------|
|     1     |       2       |       3       |
|-----------|---------------|---------------|
|     2     |       1       |       2       |
+-----------+---------------+---------------+
```

**Raw SQL to create above schema:**

```
CREATE TABLE USER (
  `UserID` int unsigned primary key,
  `First Name` varchar(4) not null,
  `Last Name` varchar(3) not null
) engine=innodb charset=utf8;

INSERT INTO USER
    (`UserID`, `First Name`, `Last Name`)
VALUES
    (1, 'John', 'Doe'),
    (2, 'Jane', 'Doe')
;



CREATE TABLE CONCERT (
  `ConcertID` int unsigned primary key,
  `Concert Name` varchar(12) not null,
  `Artist` varchar(3) not null,
  `Date` datetime not null
) engine=innodb charset=utf8;

INSERT INTO CONCERT
    (`ConcertID`, `Concert Name`, `Artist`, `Date`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Rock Concert', 'Rob', '2014-01-01 00:00:00'),
    (2, 'Rap Concert', 'Jay', '2014-02-03 00:00:00')
;



CREATE TABLE TICKET (
  `Ticket No` int unsigned primary key auto_increment,
  `UserID` int unsigned, 
  `ConcertID` int unsigned, 
  Foreign Key(`UserID`) references `USER`(`UserID`),
  Foreign Key(`ConcertID`) references `CONCERT`(`ConcertID`)
) engine=innodb charset=utf8;

INSERT INTO TICKET
    (`Ticket No`, `UserID`, `ConcertID`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 1),
    (2, 1, 2),
    (3, 2, 1)
;
```

You need to break apart your tables in such a way that you have *one-to-one* or *one-to-many* relationships without having a *many-to-many* relationship. By using a simple three table setup as described above, one user can purchase multiple tickets to multiple concerts. However, because of the itermediary table `TICKET`, we are never left with a *many-to-many* relationship. This also allows us to maintain referential integrity by tying the `UserID` in the `TICKET` table to the `UserID` in the `USER` table. In addtion, the `ConcertID` in the `TICKET` table to the `ConcertID` in the `CONCERT` table.

Finally, we are able to generate some simple queries to pull back information we need by joining the tables together. I've included two sample queries below:

**SAMPLE QUERY #1** - Retrieve all tickets of a particular user by first and last name

```
SELECT
`conc`.`Concert Name`,
`conc`.`Artist`,
`conc`.`Date`,
`tick`.`Ticket No`
FROM `CONCERT` AS `conc`
INNER JOIN `TICKET` AS `tick` ON `conc`.`ConcertID` = `tick`.`ConcertID`
INNER JOIN `USER` AS `user` ON `tick`.`UserID` = `user`.`UserID`
WHERE `user`.`First Name` = "John" AND `user`.`Last Name` = "Doe";
```

*Result:*

```
+--------------------+--------------+---------------------------------+-----------------+
|    Concert Name    |    Artist    |             Date                |    Ticket No    |
+--------------------+--------------+---------------------------------+-----------------+
|    Rock Concert    |    Rob       |  January, 01 2014 00:00:00+0000 |        1        |
|--------------------|--------------|---------------------------------|-----------------|
|    Rap Concert     |    Jay       | February, 03 2014 00:00:00+0000 |        2        |
+--------------------+--------------+---------------------------------+-----------------+
```

**SAMPLE QUERY #2** - Retrieve total number of tickets for a given concert by artist name

```
SELECT
COUNT(`tick`.`Ticket No`)
FROM `TICKET` as `tick`
INNER JOIN `CONCERT` AS `conc` ON `tick`.`ConcertID` = `conc`.`ConcertID`
WHERE `conc`.`Artist` = "Rob";
```

*Result:*

```
+--------------------+
|    Ticket Count    |
+--------------------+
|        2           |
+--------------------+
```

As an extra note, because we are using foreign key constraints, we have indexes defined on the particular columns. This helps SQL better manage and scale the queries/data leading to continued performance even with large numbers (millions) of rows.

Hope this helps. From here, you should be able to develop a lot of different queries to pull back all the information you desire. An exact working demo of the above code can be found below:

**DEMO:** [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/04c03/2)

Answer (score 0):

A compromise solution to this would be to create a new table in the same database for each concert, and to delete tables if there are space concerns. This would allow you to keep old data around without cluttering one table too much.

Comment: This seems entirely inefficient. SQL and MySQL in general is designed to scale with relational data like this.

Comment: I thought it would be efficient because when doing a search query to the database for tickets for a concert, they would all be in the one place, therefore a much faster search?